# How to use grep in linux to find all files contain a specific command?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to print the name of every C program in a specified directory tree that contains a "goto" command.

In other words, it must print the name of every file that contains "goto" as a word.
Here is what I do:

```
for fullname in `grep -r -l "\<goto\>"./*.c`;
do
  echo `basename $fullname`
done
```

but on running this I only get

> "command not found".

Comment: Why not simply `grep -l goto *.c`?

Comment: What shell are you using? This works for me after adding `#!/bin/bash
` at the top of the script (running as a .sh file)

Comment: because I want to save it as a script,so I used emacs.

Comment: I'm using linux and I have #!/bin/bash

Comment: maybe it's the way I run it.. do I just type nogoto(the name of the script) or nogoto./  ?

Comment: Can you run the `basename`command? Maybe your installation of GNU CoreUtils is messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to also search nested directories this should work

```
for fullname in $(grep -r -l "goto" . | grep ".*\.c$"); do
    echo $(basename $fullname)
done
```

Comment: I tried it, and this is what I got:grep: ./.#repeatedChars.c: No such file or directory
grep: ./.pulse/9f70fe64bb73d4adc0b23a7f00000005-runtime/native: No such device or address
grep: ./.mozilla/firefox/y5nxuwcv.default/lock: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry the * in the answer was incorrect. Remove that and try again. Are you saving this for loop in a file and calling if from the command line?

Comment: yes I saved it in emacs as "nogoto" and I call it from the command line ./nogoto

Comment: Are you calling this from a shell in Emacs? I am not an Emacs pro so I am not much on trouble shooting there but from a normal terminal if you call `bash nogoto` do you get an error?

Comment: I wonder if the "|" should be used since I'm only looking for c files

Comment: There may be other ways but the grep command in the loop above first recursively finds all of the files with `goto` in the contents then pipes that result to another grep command that only returns the files with `.c` in the name. Again when you call this from a normal (non-Emacs shell) with `bash nogoto` do you get an error?

Comment: nothing shows when I do bash nogoto  and after I did that I even lost the :~$

Comment: Then it would seem you have problems going on that are beyond the scope of your question.  I can run the exact script from the answer and I see the names of the files with a c extension that contain the string goto.

Comment: Thanks man! This time I got a lot of files but including some txt files,should I add a $ before.c?

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses instead, like this: `for fullname in $(grep -r -l "goto" . | grep ".*\.c$"); do` and `echo $(basename $fullname)`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered but the following will work for non-nested-directories.

```
grep "regex" /path/*
```

which shows

```
t.txt:Loren ip sum let etum REGEX
v.c:do_regex_match("regex","bleh");
```